# How can you use Mono's mcs to compile and run a csproj file?

Tags: c#, mono, gmcs

I'm a Unix guy who needs to try and compile some C# code for work. I've downloaded Mono for Mac, and the mcs command line tool. There's a csproj file attached to this library which contains XML with all of the files I need to compile.

Can Mono/mcs read this csproj file and generate a DLL from it?

Answer (score 66):

If you don't want to use MonoDevelop and want to use the command-line, you can use xbuild. xbuild is the Mono equivalent of MSBuild.

```
xbuild /p:Configuration=Release HelloWorld.csproj
```

Comment: xbuild is deprecated, it's call msbuild now

Comment: [Here's proof](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#xbuild) of what @deltree said

Comment: I posted the new correct method to compile and run C# in answers : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64646610/6365968

Comment: @BenjaminLucidarme this is just building some .NET app - not Mono.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to head over to [monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) and download their IDE. It can open project files generated by Visual Studio.

Now you can also use the convenience of aptitude as below:

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop mono-gmcs
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is old and answers are deprectated. I succeed to generate and run DLL from a csproj by following theses steps:

- install dotnet : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download.
  For linux, follow theses steps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux
- For ubuntu and osx you should have openssl installed `apt-get install openssl`

Then, use `dotnet build YourProject.csproj` to compile the project and `dotnet run YourProject.csproj` to run it.

Comment: This wont build .csproj on Mono