# How to link to system-installed native libraries in .NET on Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, csproj, .net-8.0

Building a project like this: `$ dotnet build <project>.csproj`
and then running it like this: `$ dotnet <project>.dll`
the program does not seem to pick up any transitive native dependencies from the system paths.

Instead it searches in .net-specific pathes, where obviously the apt-installed libraries cannot be found.

**How do I tell my .csproj to look for normal system-installed libraries in the normal system library pathes?**

Background:

I am porting some projects from Mono on Debian 10 to .net8.0 on Debian 11, using [Microsoft's upgrade-assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website#upgrade-with-the-cli-tool):

1. run the assistant, pick option "Convert project to SDK style"
2. run the assistant, pick option ".NET 8.0"
3. manually edit .csproj for each dependency not yet converted:

   - replace `<ProjectReference>` with `<Reference>` containing a `<HintPath>` to the project's output folder
4. for each dependency converted, revert 3.

So far this works fine for projects that only use Mono and .net dependencies. But whenever I have a (transitive) dependency on a native library, the program cannot find it.

E.g. `apt list --installed libglib2*` shows that I have libglib2.0 installed:

```
libglib2.0-0/oldstable,now 2.66.8-1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
libglib2.0-bin/oldstable,now 2.66.8-1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
libglib2.0-cil-dev/stable-buster,now 2.12.45-0xamarin19+debian10b1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
libglib2.0-cil/stable-buster,now 2.12.45-0xamarin19+debian10b1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
libglib2.0-data/oldstable,oldstable,now 2.66.8-1 all  [Installiert,automatisch]
```

but the program looks for it in obviously-(to-me)-wrong pathes:

```
$ dotnet bin/Debug/net8.0/<project>.dll

Gui cannot be created: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libglib-2.0-0.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider using a tool like strace. If you're using glibc, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: 
/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.0/libglib-2.0-0.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
<project>/bin/Debug/net8.0/libglib-2.0-0.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.0/liblibglib-2.0-0.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
<project>/bin/Debug/net8.0/liblibglib-2.0-0.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.0/libglib-2.0-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
<project>/bin/Debug/net8.0/libglib-2.0-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.0/liblibglib-2.0-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
<project>/bin/Debug/net8.0/liblibglib-2.0-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

   at GLib.Marshaller.g_utf16_to_utf8(Char* native_str, IntPtr len, IntPtr items_read, IntPtr items_written, IntPtr& error)
   at GLib.Marshaller.StringToPtrGStrdup(String str)
   at GLib.Global.set_ProgramName(String value)
   at Gtk.Application.SetPrgname()
   at Gtk.Application.Init()
   at <user code>
```

The package's [file listing](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/amd64/libglib2.0-0/filelist) shows that the expected path is in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

I previously worked around this issue by including the missing native library in the .csproj file in this way:

```
<Content Include="../../libiomp5.so">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

but obviously that is no good in a more-than-experimental setup.

As MonoDevelop seems to be horribly broken on Debian 11 and [xbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13665699/3434465) apparently does not support the old .csproj style anymore, it seems I cannot build the original project on Debian 11 to find out whether this is a problem with porting to .net8.0 or with porting to Debian 11.

Searches on this topic are unfortunately heavily tainted by NuGet. I do not want to use NuGet on a system where apt (, pacman, etc.) is already present. I want to use exactly the libraries provided by the distribution's maintainer.

Comment: I don‘t have an environment available to test this right now, but the runtime is - as far as I know - using the environment variable PATH to look for libraries that get loaded dynamically.

Maybe the build environment will do the same thing?

Comment: @Frank: That does not seem to suffice: I added, for the case mentioned in the OP, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` to `PATH` (and verified with `echo $PATH`), for no change in behaviour. ... I think the `dotnet` program in particular does not follow the normal OS convention but rather by default isolates "everything .NET" from "everything else". At least the pathes listed in the error message seem to indicate this to me.

Comment: Did you recognize that all the messages reference either libglib-2.0-0.dll.so or libglib-2.0-0.dll but not libglib-2.0-0.so? That seems very odd…